# Incorrect keypresses on Lenovo y560p

Tags: keyboard-layout, lenovo

Most of the keys on my Lenovo y560p work fine usually but sometimes some of them will register incorrect keypresses.

For example, the <kbd>u</kbd> key will register as "volume up", the <kbd>n</kbd> will be "ESC".  But most of the others will be fine.  USB keyboards work fine.  Seems to happen intermittently.

Laptop: Lenovo y560p
Ubuntu: 10.04 LTS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a hardware issue, as I installed Windows 7 and the same keyboard issues appeared.

Was covered by Lenovo warranty. They exchanged it.

Answer (score 2):

You might have one of two issues:

Either a hardware issue and your laptop is having problems with the cable or circuit related to the keyboard or a misconfiguration of the keyboard layout when Ubuntu was installed or after it was installed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem actually is the keyboard ribbon that plugs into the motherboard.  Same issue happened to me.  The ribbon rubs on a sharp edge on a heat sink, eventually grounding out after some time.

Solution:  I used a small strip of electrical tape to insulate the ribbon where the heat sink rubbed it and exposed the small conductive material inside.  I haven't had an issue since.

The heat sink is a bad design flaw that Lenovo should fix!