# Wrong random keypresses on HP business notebooks running Ubuntu

Tags: kernel, keyboard, hp

I experience an issue with a number of units of HP EliteBook 1040 G9 which is certified with Ubuntu (source: https://ubuntu.com/certified/202203-30040). From time to time pressing one key results in a completely different input to the system altogether. For example, sometimes pressing the Super key results in g or ].

Initially, I suspected interference or errors on the USB bus from external USB peripherals, so I deployed other peripherals, except for monitors which we cannot change, but the problem continued. Later on, I tried different Ubuntu versions, specifically Ubuntu 22.04.2 with the generic kernel 5.19 and the OEM kernel 6.1, and also Ubuntu 23.04 with the generic kernel 6.2. Nothing has resolved the issue. I also tried replacing the keyboards and touchpads in the affected systems, but the problem persists.

I have found a similar problem ([Incorrect keypresses on Lenovo y560p](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67919/incorrect-keypresses-on-lenovo-y560p)), but that was a pure hardware damage. With HP EliteBook 1040 G9 it occurs even with a brand new keyboard, touchpad and palmrest.

Do you have any ideas what might be causing the issue?